# Using "this" keyword when creating an eventhandler

Tags: java, android

I have the following Java code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    Button btn;
    TextView textview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnGoToSecondActivity);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        secondActivityIntent.putExtra("Name", textview.getText());
        startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

Every bit of code makes sense until I hit the "this" keyword in the example above.
I can't get my head around the "this" keyword used as an argument in the "setOnClickListener()" method call.. 
I haven't created an instance of any of the used classes above. How can I refer to an instance that is non-existing? Is the instance created automatically?

(I know what the "this" keyword is and what it does, but in this case I don't see the logic)

Comment: still searching ? or need any help? if need help join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10629/agarwal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this line of code:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

... is stating that the event listener for the button, is the same instance you're currently on - given that the class it belongs to (`FirstActivity`) implements the `OnClickListener` interface.

And yes, there *is* an instance already created when you call this method, otherwise you wouldn't be able to call the method at all! You happen to be passing as an argument to `setOnClickListener` the *current* instance you're on at the time of invoking the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You asked "Is the instance created automatically?" and the answer to that is, effectively, yes. Your application *is* an instance of this Activity class; the instance gets created by the framework and is used by the framework to handle various events.

Answer (score 2):

If you're executing a non-static method like onCreate() then the object obviously exists. Your Activity object is invoked by Android (that's why you have to include it in the manifest).

Answer (score 1):

Your class is FirstActivity, which implements the OnClickListener interface, inside the methods of FirstActivity, "this" is a reference to the the instance of the class FirstActivity where the methods are run in. (When the Android runs the activity , it creates a instance of this class).

Since FirstActivity is also a OnClickListener, you pass the instance of the FirstActivity class to setOnClickListener method.